# How to parse a large XML file using JQUERY and visualize it in HTML format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a java web application where the requirement is to upload XML file of a specific format and then parse it to represent it in an HTML UI. The UI representation of the XML tags should be editable. Can this be done using JQUERY?

I tried using jParse but did not find the entire stuff(other than the .js file) to be used within my existing project.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This setting goes in your web.config file. It affects the entire application, though... I don't think you can set it per page.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
    <!-- your required file size on place of "xxx" -->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

*NOTE:* It's in KB. The default is 4096 Kb (= 4 MB).

If you are using IIS 7+ then, setting is little different now.

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" /> <!--50MB-->
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

### If you are using JAVA:

Edit the `server.xml` for that particular server, either the application server process or the deployment manager process depending on what process suffers from the memory problem.
So, edit the `initialHeapSize` and `MaximumHeapSize` as,

```
jvmEntries debugArgs="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=7777"   
debugMode="false" disableJIT="false" genericJvmArguments="-Xquickstart"   
runHProf="false" verboseModeClass="false"  
initialHeapSize="512" maximumHeapSize="1024"  
verboseModeGarbageCollection="false" verboseModeJNI="false" xmi:id="JavaVirtualMachine_1183121908656"
```

The `server.xml` can be found here:

> /*IBM_ROOT_DIR*/WebSphere/WAS85/AppServer/profiles/MyProfile/config/cells/MyCell/nodes/MyNode/servers/MyServer/server.xml

Comment: can you please let me know an approach as to how I should load this file and parse it in jQuery?

Comment: Are you developing application in Visual Studio

Comment: It is a Java web application so the IDE used is Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Vikrant. Just to make it more lucid on our requirement:-

We would need to design a java tool to :
1.  Capture an xml file
2.  Represent the data in a visually depictable form
3.  Allow easy edits to the existing structure after successful upload
4.  Export the new structure to an output form which can be ingested by the application

The key drivers for the tool are:
1.  It needs to be easily editable
2.  Should be re-usable for iterative inputs ( considering the first-cycle output will be the next cycle’s input file)